# delete row on update of associate table update in postgresSql

Tags: postgresql

i have two tables author and books with one to many relation (fk authorId) and i want to delete author who have no book row associated after deletion of book or updating author name in books table so that author with no book associated should get deleted,
so do i need to do it manually every time or is there any other way to do it

Comment: 2 questions: Are you deleting an author because there is no book associated with them or are you deleting an author because you are also deleting a book from the `books` table, which happens to be the only book from that author (i.e. after deletion, there is no more book associated with them)? How are you doing it right now?

Comment: yes deleting book or updating books author name also make previous author having no book associate

Comment: Then **edit** your question with the answer to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could do it:

```
DELETE FROM books bk
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
SELECT FROM author au
WHERE  bk.authorId = au.authorId
);
```